# randomly display a div class using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I want to randomly display a div class using JQuery. The code is something like:

```
<div class="item">One</div>
<div class="item">Two</div>
<div class="item">Three</div>
<div class="item">Four</div>
```

So if the random method(random result is within 1 to 4) gives 3 as the result, it shows:

```
<div class="item">Three</div>
```

The rest are hidden. Of course, the code can be changed to make it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 27):

First we get a random int, from zero to the number of items (minus 1). 
Then we hide all other elements and show just the randomly chosen one.

```
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * jQuery('.item').length);
jQuery('.item').hide().eq(random).show();
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hrAHT/1/)**

Comment: I have the same function , but how to go about two random div to be displayed. Should I run it twice.?

Answer (score 3):

```
var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*3)
var div = $(".item")[number];
div.show();
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like that :

```
$('.item').hide().eq(Math.floor(Math.random()*4)).show()
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/PPXmE/

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't show your answer for this question.

Answer (score 2):

Working example: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hrAHT/3/)

## js

```
window.onload=function() {
  var E = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
  var m = E.length;
  var n = parseInt(Math.random()*m);
  for (var i=m-1;i>=0;i--) {
      var e = E[i];
      e.style.display='none';
  }
  E[n].style.display='';
}
```

## js.minified

```
window.onload=function(){var E=document.getElementsByClassName("item");var m=E.length;var n=parseInt(Math.random()*m);for(var i=m-1;i>=0;i--){var e=E[i];e.style.display='none';}E[n].style.display='';}
```

## html

```
<div class="item">One</div>
<div class="item">Two</div>
<div class="item">Three</div>
<div class="item">Four</div>
<div class="item">Five</div>
<div class="item">Six</div>
<!-- Add as many as you want! //-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the setInterval function.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/a0c0ntjc/

```
setInterval(function(){
        var E=document.getElementsByClassName("item");
        var m=E.length;
        var n=parseInt(Math.random()*m);for(var i=m-1;i>=0;i--){
            var e=E[i];e.style.display='none';
        }
        E[n].style.display='';
},3000);
```