# loading random <p> on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, random

I've been slowly learning jQuery in the past year, I have to assume I'm just asking the question wrong since I can't find the answer.

In my header, I have a div for different "taglines". I want only one of them to display per refresh, and randomly (pseudo or truly random doesn't matter).

**Markup:**

```
<div id="tagline">
    <p>Tagline #1</p>
    <p>Tagline #2</p>
    <p>Tagline #3</p>
    <p>Tagline #4</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#tagline p {display: none;}
```

I'm not sure the jQuery that is involved to make only one display at a time. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: var randomTag = Math.floor(Math.random()*4);

But no equation I wrote did anything at all, that was as far as I got.

Comment: post the full jquery code.

Comment: @d_macarty: Do you have a pure client-side application or do you generate your markup on the server?

Comment: @wolle This is pure client-side

Comment: possible duplicate of [randomly display a div class using JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18476614/randomly-display-a-div-class-using-jquery)

Comment: @Mritunjay 

var randomTag = Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
   var randomTag = new Array()
    randomTag[0] = 'Tagline #1',
    randomTag[1] = 'Tagline #2',
    randomTag[2] = 'Tagline #3',
    randomTag[3] = 'Tagline #4';
   document.write(randomTag);

Comment: @Dan there was a jsFiddle on that page that looks like it's what I'm trying to accomplish, thanks!

Comment: The solutions below are good. I thought this was a neat little plugin worth a look though, might be worth grabbing if you are going to want to use similar functionality throughout your app -

http://blog.mastykarz.nl/jquery-random-filter/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code and example. This will work if you add more taglines as well.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var taglineNo = Math.floor(Math.random()*$('#tagline p').length);
    $('#tagline p:eq(' + taglineNo + ')').show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5qf7krj9/1/

Comment: That's much more handy actually.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
$("#tagline p").eq(random).css('display', 'block');
```

Comment: That assumes that there will always be four taglines.

Comment: Probably better to do something like `$('#tagline > p:nth-child(' + random + ')').css('display','block');` because that guarantees you select only the `<p>` elements in the `#tagline` div.