# JS: Hide random element within

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="all">
  <div class="single">A</div>
  <div class="single">B</div>
  <div class="single">C</div>
</div>

<div class="all">
  <div class="single">A</div>
  <div class="single">B</div>
  <div class="single">C</div>
</div>
```

I'd like to run some JavaScript/jQuery on page load that shows a random "single" div within each of the "all" divs. If I use the code, [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18476614/randomly-display-a-div-class-using-jquery), one of the "single" divs shows up between both of the "all" divs as apposed to a "single" div appear in each of the "all" divs.

```
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.single').length);
$('.single').hide().eq(random).show();
```

I tried and failed to write some sort of loop that cycles through all instances of "all" and reveals one of the "single" divs, but to no avail as my JS skills are extremely poor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call your code on each member of the `$('.all')` collection:

```js
$('.all').each(function() {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.single', this).length);
  $('.single', this).hide().eq(random).show();
});
```

```css
.all {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="all">
  <div class="single">A</div>
  <div class="single">B</div>
  <div class="single">C</div>
</div>

<div class="all">
  <div class="single">A</div>
  <div class="single">B</div>
  <div class="single">C</div>
</div>
```